# Method to Return a Parsed Decimal Does not Compile

Tags: c#

I was wondering the reason why this block of code won't compile.

```
public decimal? GetDecimalValue(String decimalString)
{
    return decimalString.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? null : decimal.Parse(decimalString);
}
```

ERROR Message: `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'decimal'`

However, if I write the ternary statement out, then it works.

```
public decimal? GetDecimalValueThisOneCompiles(String decimalString)
{
    if(decimalString.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) return null;
    return decimal.Parse(decimalString);
}
```

Comment: the ternary operator needs to return the same type for either scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast `null` to `decimal?` and you have to pass `decimalString` to `decimal.Parse`, not `string` keyword:

```
public decimal? GetDecimalValue(String decimalString)
{
    return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(decimalString) ? (decimal?)null : decimal.Parse(decimalString);
}
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I assumed OP has an extension method declared to make `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` calls easier.

Comment: May be but first look gives that it would be a compiler error for sure.

Comment: Typo on my part. Meant to say decimalString but yes, casting null to nullable decimal solved the issue. I still think its strange to have to cast null to a nullable type.